# Windows store app pause when navigating between pages

Tags: c#, performance, user-interface, windows-store-apps

I'm building a Windows Store App using the OOTB Grid App template.  I'm noticing that there is a 500-1000 millisecond pause when I am navigating from page to page either forward or backward.  It is mainly noticeable when I hit the back button (the back arrow stays in the "Hit" state for the 500-1000 ms). Going forward isn't as bad because usually the screen has animations and transitions to fill most of the loading times.

My first thought was that there was something on in the `LoadState` method that was causing the slowdown, but the only thing I have that isn't from the template I'm running on a background thread and calling it with an `async` preface.

My second thought was that I was passing a complex object to each page's `navigationParameter` instead of just passing a simple string.  I didn't think this could be the cause since the object should be pass by reference so there really shouldn't be any slowdown because I passed a non-string into the `NavigateTo` method.

*(I haven't read any guidance about this, so I don't know if the page navigation is less snappy when passing non-strings between pages.  If anyone has any insight into this, that would be wonderful)*

My next thought was that my Xaml is too complex and the pause is the Xaml loading all of the items into the list and what not.  This might be the issue and if so, I have no idea how to test or fix it. The UI feels fluid once everything is loaded (all of the items on the page scroll without stutter)

If this is the case, is there any way to show a loading circle with the Xaml generates and then once it is done generating, fade the content in and the circle out?

The main thing that I want to fix is I don't want the back button to "freeze" in the Hit.  Any help or guidance would be great!

---

### Basic app info:

Pages have combinations of List and Grid View controls with different Item templates.  No images or graphics are used, but I do use a gradient brush on some of the item templates (not super complex, similar to the start screen item gradients).  Most lists only have 20-30 items, some more most less.

The average page has 1 Item Source, and 2 Item Display controls, a list and a scroll viewer that holds the details of the selected item.

Details for any item are about 2-3 normal paragraphs of details text and 3-4 < 20 char strings.

---

EDIT:  Project Code:

### Page 1 code

```
    protected async override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
    {
        if (navigationParameter == null)
            this.DefaultViewModel["Groups"] = GlobalData.Catalog.Catalog;
        else
            this.DefaultViewModel["Groups"] = navigationParameter;

        await GlobalData.LibraryDownload.DiscoverActiveDownloadsAsync();
    }
```

The `DiscoverActiveDownloadsAsync` method is the same code from [this example code](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Transfer-Sample-d7833f61/sourcecode?fileId=52027&pathId=238539495)

`SaveState`, `OnNavigateTo`, and `OnNavigateFrom` methods haven't been modified from the `LayoutAwarePage` base class.

### Page 2 code

```
    protected async override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
    {
        if (navigationParameter is CatalogBook)
        {
            var catBook = (CatalogBook)navigationParameter;
            var book = catBook.Book;
            await book.InitializeAsync();

            this.DefaultViewModel["Group"] = catBook;
            this.DefaultViewModel["Items"] = book.Items;
        }
        else if (navigationParameter is IBook)
        {
            var book = await Task.Run<IBook>(async () =>
                {
                    var b = (IBook)navigationParameter;
                    await b.InitializeAsync();
                    return b;
                });

            this.DefaultViewModel["Group"] = book;
            this.DefaultViewModel["Items"] = book.Chapters;
        }

        if (pageState == null)
        {
            // When this is a new page, select the first item automatically unless logical page
            // navigation is being used (see the logical page navigation #region below.)
            if (!this.UsingLogicalPageNavigation() && this.itemsViewSource.View != null)
            {
                this.itemsViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Restore the previously saved state associated with this page
            if (pageState.ContainsKey("SelectedItem") && this.itemsViewSource.View != null)
            {
                var number = 0;
                if(!int.TryParse(pageState["SelectedItem"].ToString(), out number)) return;

                var item = itemsViewSource.View.FirstOrDefault(i => i is ICanon && ((ICanon)i).Number == number);
                if (item == null) return;

                this.itemsViewSource.View.MoveCurrentTo(item);

                itemListView.UpdateLayout();
                itemListView.ScrollIntoView(item);
            }
        }
    }


    ...


    protected override void SaveState(Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
    {
        if (this.itemsViewSource.View != null)
        {
            var selectedItem = this.itemsViewSource.View.CurrentItem;
            pageState["SelectedItem"] = ((ICanon)selectedItem).Number;
        }
    }
```

The `InitializeAsync` method reads from an SQLite database some of the basic information about a book (chapters, author, etc.) and generally runs very quickly (< 10ms)

### Grid code

I get the data by querying an SQLite database using the SQLite-net Nuget Package's async methods.  The queries usually look something like this:

```
    public async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        var chapters = await _db.DbContext.Table<ChapterDb>().Where(c => c.BookId == Id).OrderBy(c => c.Number).ToListAsync();

        Chapters = chapters
            .Select(c => new Chapter(_db, c))
            .ToArray();

        HeaderText = string.Empty;
    }
```

I populate the grids by using the following Xaml:

```
    <CollectionViewSource
        x:Name="groupedItemsViewSource"
        Source="{Binding Groups}"
        IsSourceGrouped="true"
        ItemsPath="Items"
        d:Source="{Binding DisplayCatalog, Source={d:DesignInstance Type=data:DataCatalog, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}"/>

    <common:CatalogItemTemplateSelector x:Key="CatalogItemTemplateSelector" />

    ...

    <GridView
        Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageLightBackgroundThemeBrushGradient}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}" 
        SelectionMode="Multiple"            
        Grid.Row="1" 
        ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource CatalogItemTemplateSelector}" 
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick" Margin="-40,0,0,0">
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="628" Margin="120,10,0,0" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <GridView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="1,10,0,6">
                            <Button
                                AutomationProperties.Name="Group Title"
                                Click="Header_Click"
                                Style="{StaticResource TextPrimaryButtonStyle}" >
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="3,-7,10,10" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource ChevronGlyph}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Margin="0,-7,0,10" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <GroupStyle.Panel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VariableSizedWrapGrid Margin="0,0,80,0" ItemHeight="{StaticResource ItemHeight}" ItemWidth="{StaticResource ItemWidth}"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.Panel>
            </GroupStyle>
        </GridView.GroupStyle>

    </GridView>
```

the `CatalogItemTemplateSelector` class looks like this:

```
public class CatalogItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        // cast item to your custom item class
        var customItem = item as ICatalogItem;
        if (customItem == null)
            return null;

        string templateName = String.Empty;
        if (customItem is CatalogFolder || customItem is CatalogMoreFolder)
        {
            templateName = "FolderItemDataTemplate";
        }
        else if (customItem is CatalogBook || customItem is CatalogMoreBook)
        {
            templateName = "BookItemDataTemplate";
        }

        object template = null;
        // find template in App.xaml
        Application.Current.Resources.TryGetValue(templateName, out template);
        return template as DataTemplate;
    }
}
```

Both of the templates are ~20 lines of Xaml, nothing special

If there are other pieces of code that I haven't included, let me know and I'll add them.

Comment: Passing complex types to NavigateTo is bad practice.

Comment: Do you have a link to any documentation that talks about this?  I've been looking and I can't find anything that says that passing complex types to NavigateTo is a bad practice

Comment: @joe_coolish - it is really hard to tell what could be wrong without any code. Can you post samples of the following methods: `LoadState`, `SaveState`, `OnNavigateTo`, `OnNavigateFrom`. Also, it would be good to see how you 1) get the data for your Grid, and 2) populate the grid.

Comment: @chuex I've added the code for you.  Let me know if I forgot to add something

Comment: I don't see anything too obvious. The only thing that I would look at is the call to `DiscoverActiveDownloadsAsync`. When I was looking at `BackgroundDownloader` previously, it seemed that the correct thing to do was to make the `DiscoverActiveDownloadsAsync` call only at startup (I could be wrong). You are, in contrast, doing this every time the page gets loaded. Do you have any event handlers on your pages to do progress reporting for the downloads? If so, you might be causing multiple page instances to hang around (memory leak). Try commenting out the call and see if that makes a difference

Comment: Have you got the same problem with other apps?

Comment: I have other example apps that I've built that do not have the same lag issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does your memory usage look like? Might you be paging to disk?

Excerpt From http://paulstovell.com/blog/wpf-navigation

> Page Lifecycles ....
>   Suppose your page required some kind of parameter data to be passed to it: 
>   ... When navigating, if you click
>   "Back", WPF can't possibly know what values to pass to the
>   constructor; therefore it must keep the page alive.
>   ... If you navigate passing an object directly, WPF will keep the object alive.

Comment: I'm curious about this.  My memory usage is < 200 mb with a full book loaded, ~100 mb pre book loading after navigating around, and ~50 mb right after the app finishes loading.  I'm running my app on a Surface RT after a fresh boot with > 1gb of RAM available.  How do I check if my navigation is paging to disk?

Comment: @joe_coolish The easiest way is probably via task manager - go to the "Processes" tab, select "View -> Select  Columns", and check "Page Faults" and "Page Fault Delta".  Then just look at the values for your app's process.  It is also quite likely that perfmon has a performance counter or two with that information. However, the memory usage you've stated doesn't sound incredibly excessive.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer, but this Channel 9 (Microsoft) video is pretty good regarding XAML performance. Maybe it can help you in your problem.

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/4-103

Comment: I've gone through and watched the video before I asked the question.  I will re-watch and re-evaluate the tips presented in the training